# Where is stored an app path on an android device?

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo

I use an application on my samsung tablet (gt-p1000) that must store some settings somewhere and sometime I have to erase the application data to unlock the app, but this way too much things are removed then I would like to just remove the files that store specific informations.
Where can I find them or maybe how to edit some registry keys ?

THanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use the same mechanism that you used to store your data. It's not clear from your question what you do, but I can think of 2 things:

if you use preferences, then you need to clear them the same way you set them (as they're not stored in a file as you think of it, it's more like a database)

if you store actual files, then you should know the directory, as you wrote a file in it.